# how to pick two characters at a time from a string? reaching ith position of a string?

Tags: c++, string, char

how should i run a for loop to pick two characters at a time from my string??

```
int main{
string data;
for (i = 0; i <= data.size(); i+=2)
d = data[i] + data[i+1];
cout << "the list of two characters at a time is" << d;
}
```

//i want to pick divide my string(data) for example: "hello how are you" into a list of two characters at a time (where the space should also be counted as a character) and listed such as:

```
cout should give:

he

ll 

o(space)

ho

w(space)

ar

e(space)

yo

u //the last one is appended with 8 zeros with u to make a complete pair
```

i dont understand how to reach the ith position of string data in C++.

Comment: Just to avoid some crashes... I would recommend `assert(data.size() % 2 == 0);` or some sort of check before the loop. Without that, if there is an odd number of letters, you will have an off by one error, and potentially a crash. Perhaps if it has an odd size, you should just append a "\x00" to the string, to enforce it being even sized?

Comment: exactly! thats what i specified :) the last 8 bytes (or odd character) should be appended with zeros.

Answer (score 4):

How about you use `substr()`?

```
for (int i=0; i<data.length(); i+=2) {
    if(i+2 < data.length()){              //prevent it from throwing out_of_range exception
        d = data.substr(i,i+2);
        cout << d << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't even think of that, nice one

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right except 2 issues:

1. you loop condition is wrong, it could be this:

   `for (i = 0; i + 1 < data.size(); i+=2)`

   otherwise you will try to access data behind end of string. In this case you will skip 1 symbol if string length is odd. If you need to process that, your loop should be different.
2. you add 2 chars as numbers, but you should make it as string:

   `d = std::string( data[i] ) + data[i+1];`

Comment: I get an error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' when i use what you've specified in 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::cout << "the list of two characters at a time is:\n";
for (i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
    if (data[i] == ' ')
        std::cout << "(space)";
    else
        std::cout << data[i];
    if (i % 2 != 0)
        std::cout << '\n';
}
```